# steps for creating complex relations between tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Here (http://allaboutruby.wordpress.com/2009/08/08/5-minute-project-in-rails/) we can see how to create 1-m relation between tables, but what steps should I do to create for example the next kind of the relations between tables:
[image]

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/issue_track_obj.htm

To simplify, just how to create the relation where `user can have several created by him bugs and can be assigned to the several bugs created by other users.`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need two columns on bugs table, creator_id and assignee_id. Then you just create following relationships:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :created_bugs, :class_name => 'Bug', :foreign_key => :creator_id
  has_many :assigned_bugs, :class_name => 'Bug', :foreign_key => :assignee_id
end

class Bug < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => 'User'
end
```